Ubuntu laptop not getting complaint with Intune portal
I've encountered an issue with some Ubuntu laptops. These laptops have automatically stopped syncing with Intune (company portal). This seems to be related to a known issue between Microsoft and Ubuntu.
To address the situation I have performed the following steps:

I formatted all the Ubuntu laptops to versions 20.04 and 22.04. During this process, all laptops were successfully registered on the Intune portal, after 1-2 months, all laptops were automatically deregistered from the portal.

I have reinstalled the company portal on multiple laptops, but no luck. It has encountered synchronization issues.


Errors:



"all laptops were automatically deregistered from the portal." so it works .... you likely need to take this up with the admin on the other end of the portal. This smells like a certification issue.

we've observed with the Intune app and the Company Portal app on our laptops. After reimaging the laptop, the Intune app allows login and shows compliance on the admin portal. However, we encounter an error when attempting to log in or sync with the Company Portal app.
While reformatting the laptop temporarily resolves the issue, the same problem reappears after about a week. This cycle of reimaging and reoccurrence suggests that the underlying issue may require a more permanent solution

Basically issue with ubuntu that users not able to login company portal app (Intune) after 15days or 1 month from formatting time

to me those 2 have nothing to do with eachother. it is more likely intune logs out after 15 days and then changes the login credentials.
